# Does the linux kernel crypto module support the padding operation in cbc(aes) algorithm?

Tags: encryption, linux-kernel, padding

My Linux kernel version is 3.10.27. And I want to use the linux kernel crypto user-space api to encrypt the files in user space. The mode is 'cbc', and the cipher is 'aes-128'. If the data length is not aligned to a block size, the padding operation should be used in the data end to ensure encryption success, such as pkcs7padding and so on.

I want to know whether the kernel crypto module achieve the function of padding, or the padding operation should be realized in the application in user-space?

Thank you for your attention.